# VideoView in fragment width: match_parent heigh: wrap_content

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-relativelayout, android-videoview

I'm trying to put a VideoView in a fragment (portrait mode), I need it to match parent's width, and wrap its height to keep aspect ratio.
Here's my fragment layout...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/img1">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/myVideo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/myVideo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="70dp"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And it's not working, the height fits all the screen (like height: match_parent)...
If I put a defined size to height (for example 200dp), it works, but it doesn't keep aspect ratio...

Thanks in advance

Comment: put height to  "-1dp" and check

Comment: No, it continues matching all the screen.